# Fixed effects, random effects and mixed effect modelling

Tags: mixed-model, exploratory-data-analysis

I performed an incubation study to evaluate the effect of 4 fertilizer types on available P content in soil. I applied the fertilizers in 3 different soil types. I also had 4 replicates for each treatment combination. One soil had a high initial P content while the other had low P content. However, the fertilizers behaved almost in a similar manner across all three soils. So, I performed a linear mixed model in R by considering fertilizers as fixed effect and soils as a random effect. The results showed a significant effect of fertilizer types. So, I wanted to present the results of this analysis. I tried to make boxplots but looking at the chart, the  data spread is very wide because one of the soil initially had very high P content. What do you suggest is the best way to analyze such data? Also, should I include replication as a fixed/random effect or can I ignore it since it was a study done inside an incubator?
I would greatly appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.